# How to read picke files using pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, apache-arrow

I have a bunch of code for reading multiple `pickle` files using ***Pandas***:

```
dfs = []
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"../data/simulated-data-raw/", "*.pkl")):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            temp = pd.read_pickle(f)
            dfs.append(temp)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = df.append(dfs)
```

how can I read the files using `pyarrow`? Meanwhile, this way does not work and raises an error.

```
dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "../data/simulated-data-raw/", "*.pkl")):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        temp = pa.read_serialized(f)
        dfs.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(dfs)
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, `pyarrow.read_serialized` is deprecated and you should just use arrow `ipc` or python standard `pickle` module when willing to serialize data.

Anyway I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, saving objects with Pickle will try to deserialize them with the same exact type they had on save, so even if you don't use pandas to load back the object, you will still get back a pandas DataFrame (as that's what you pickled) and will still need pandas installed to be able to create one.

For example, you can easily get rid of `pandas.read_pickle` and replace it with just `pickle.load`, but what you get back will still be a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
original_df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": range(5), "bar": range(5, 10)})
pd.to_pickle(original_df, "./dummy.pkl")

import pickle
loaded_back = pickle.load(open("./dummy.pkl", "rb"))
print(loaded_back)
```

Comment: Thanks! but my Q was mainly around that how can I load a pickle using arrow.  then, you mentioned I do not need to load pickle using `arrow`. Still, Basically, I am looking for the most memory-efficient way to save and load a pickle - assuming that pandas.read_pickle() is not the best, As, reading the CSV files with pyarrow is much more efficient.

Comment: Pickle is not exactly designed with performance as its core value. I guess that with pickle version 5 that improved a lot thanks to zero copy support, but in generral I'd suggest you switch to using a different marshaling format if performance is what you care about.

For example you might consider converting those files to the Arrow IPC format, it has a convenience method that reads back data to a pandas dataframe ( https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#reading-from-stream-and-file-format-for-pandas ) and it should be faster than `pandas.read_pickle`